# python pillow having issues

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

I am receiving the below error while trying to use pillow:

```
ImportError    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-0da89a82785c> in <module>()
      1 # load the example image and convert it to grayscale
----> 2 from PIL import Image
      3 import pytesseract
      4 #No preprocessing required here as the results are fairly good.
      5 text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('C:\\Users\\karan\\Desktop\\allTables.jpg'))

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py in <module>()
     93     # Also note that Image.core is not a publicly documented interface,
     94     # and should be considered private and subject to change.
---> 95     from . import _imaging as core
     96 
     97     if __version__ != getattr(core, "PILLOW_VERSION", None):

ImportError: cannot import name '_imaging'
```

I tried uninstalling and installing pillow as well as deleting PIL file but nothing helped.

Comment: Welcome to SO. When asking a question, please try to be as specific as you can about your problem and provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code [within your question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).